# PHP, Limit user input incorrect value x time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to limit user input for a code that the user inputs incorrectly when the user forgot his/her password. I'm doing a for loop and inside the loop i give a if statement. The code is sent to their email and they have to input the code before they can change the password. Looks like my code is wrong.

```html
<?php
for($count=0;$count<5;$count++)
  { 
   if($code != str_replace($unnecessary2, "", $validcode) && $count < 5)
   {
    http_response_code(406); 
    echo '[{"message":"code is invalid!"}]';
    $count = $count+1;
    die();
   }
   else if($code != str_replace($unnecessary2, "", $validcode) && $count == 5)
   {
    $deletedata="delete from personal_password_reset where email='".$dt[0]["email"]."'";
    run_sql($deletedata);
    
    http_response_code(406); 
    echo '[{"message":"you have entered invalid code 5 times, please request a new code."}]';
    
    die();
   }
   else
   {
    http_response_code(200); 
    echo '[{"message":"code is valid!"}]';
    die();
   }
  }
?>
```

When the code is incorrect for the 5th time, the user should get the second message `you have entered invalid code 5 times, please request a new code.`. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Your loop will only ever execute once, you have `die()` in every option.

Comment: How do you call this code?

Comment: You don't need to cycle it. This check will be dun for every user request.  You need to save somewhere attempt every time when you receive request from the user. You can do it in SESSION, file, database. What do you prefer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store this kind of info in session.

Define threshold and then keep storing the attempts

```
 if(FAILED_LOGIN_CASE)///  {


   if($_SESSION['failedAttempts']== Threshold) {
        ///attempts exceeded
   }
   else{
    $_SESSION['failedAttempts']= $_SESSION['failedAttempts'] + 1;
   }
 }
 else{
  //login 
   $_SESSION['failedAttempts']=0;
 }
```

In case of successful login, set the session to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Session** and save a counter for invalid counts after that each time user enters invalid information set counter++ and at last, commit that to the Session.
Finally for control that checks

```
if(Session['YOUR_SESSION'] == 5)
// your code place here
```

Comment: I think you can include some more code. How to set up a session  etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you are testing for $count == 5.

```
else if($code != str_replace($unnecessary2, "", $validcode) && $count == 5)
```

Count will never take the value of 5 since the for loop is stopping on $count < 5.

```
for($count=0;$count<5;$count++)
```